# C++ function template: Must use & for argument type and return type?

Tags: c++, function, templates

I'm learning to use function template. I find that if I declare the argument type as a reference, the program will work. But I get error if the argument type is not reference. For example:

The following code prints the correct result and works with no error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T & max (T & a, T & b){
    return a>b?a:b;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    cout << max(1,2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But if I remove all the "`&`" in the code, i.e. change the above program as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T  max (T  a, T  b){
    return a>b?a:b;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    cout << max(1,2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code will lead to the following error.

```
a.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
a.cpp:11:17: error: call of overloaded ‘max(int, int)’ is ambiguous
  cout << max(1,2) << endl;
                 ^
a.cpp:5:4: note: candidate: T max(T, T) [with T = int]
 T  max (T  a, T  b){
    ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/char_traits.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:39,
                 from a.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:219:5: note: candidate: constexpr const _Tp& std::max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = int]
     max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
```

Why?
Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: compiler tells you: your call of max is ambiguous, i presume because there is max template in std namespace

Comment: One more reason why not to use `using namespace std;`

Comment: the first example is invalid and you are not using your template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already function (template) with same (or compatible) name and parameter types defined in std namespace.

Remove

```
using namespace std;
```

And prefix the cout and endl with std::

```
std::cout << max(1,2) << std::endl;
```

Otherwise you have polluted your global namespace with all the names in the std namespace.

Answer (score 2):

The reference param version isn't considered in the first example because those constants don't qualify for modifiable lvalue references. And thanks to the ill-advised `using namespace std;`, you're pulling in the `std` version instead, which will work. You could *remove* your `max` code in the first version and it will still work, because it isn't considered once those references trigger disqualification.

In short, the first version doesn't consider your `max` code because it doesn't qualify, so `std::max` is used instead (which *does* qualify). In the second version, both your code using value arguments, and the `std::max` version using const-references, can qualify, so the result in ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

There is a templated `max()` function that accepts to arguments in namespace `std` (in standard header `<algorithm>`).  Although the standard doesn't require that function be introduced by `#include <iostream>`, it also doesn't forbid it.   Your standard compiler does introduce it via `<iostream>`.

The using directive (`using namespace std`) causes `std::max()` templates to be considered as candidates for matching functions in your code.

In your first code sample, the call `max(1,2)` is matched by `std::max()` since that accepts `const` references, and is a better match than your function which accepts non-`const` references.   It happens to produce the output you expect.

In your second code sample, passing by value, the compiler has no reason to prefer either your `max()` or the one in `std`  (passing by value or passing by `const` reference are both equally valid for passing an `int` literal like `1` or `2`).   Hence the compiler complains about ambiguity.

The catch is:  with different compilers (or their standard libraries) your code may fail differently, since `<iostream>` is not required to declare `std::max()`, and not all implementations do.

Remove the using directive, and the potential usage of `std::max()` in your code will disappear - `std::max()` will not be considered as a candidate in either of your code samples.   Your first sample will not compile, since a non-`const` reference can not be used to pass literal values.   The second will compile and produce the output you expect.     This behaviour will be consistent between standard-compliant C++ compilers (and not affected whether standard headers like `<iostream>` declare `std::max()` or not).